# Perform math on dynamically updating JavaScript Value

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have figured out how to update my html dynamically based on the current input of a form. However, I am stumped with how to perform any math on this value (i.e. value*5), and display that result, instead of merely displaying the value in the form.

Here is a live example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14749627/happy2/number.html

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

var purchase_quantity = document.getElementById('purchase_quantity');
purchase_quantity.onclick = updateNameDisplay;
purchase_quantity.onclick = updateNameDisplay;
purchase_quantity.onclick = updateNameDisplay;
function updateNameDisplay() {
  document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = this.value || "1";
 }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you repeat `purchase_quantity.onclick = updateNameDisplay;`?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = this.value*5 || "1";` ?

Answer (score 1):

Campari's solution works, but you should convert it to a Number explicitly as a good habit.  If you [tried to add instead](http://jsfiddle.net/b2xvM/2/), it wouldn't work as expected.  Also, thanks to Oriol for pointing out the other problem.

```
var purchase_quantity = document.getElementById('purchase_quantity');
purchase_quantity.onclick = updateNameDisplay;

function updateNameDisplay() {
    document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = 
        this.value.length ? Number(this.value) * 5 : "1";
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2xvM/)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, now I see the problem. The obvious solution

```
document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = this.value*5 || "1";
```

doesn't work because if `this.value` is `"0"`, then `"0"*5` is `0`, which is falsy, so `"1"` is returned instead.

Then, you can use something like

```
document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = (this.value || "1") * 5;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = this.value ? this.value*5 : "1";
```

depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To get your value x 5? Pretty simple:

```
document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = this.value * 5 || "1";
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ga6A4/).

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you are saying correctly, then you want to store the elements data as a variable.

var result = this.value * 5;
document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = result;

If I misinterpreted your question please correct me.

Comment: Or you could do it simply like @Campari suggested.  Id vote you up but I don't have reputation enough, just joined.